# I want to to be able to print the name of the keys in the dictionary then the description, value and quantity

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

what i want the output to look like is this:

```
IM. Iced Milo (S$1.5) Qty:  2 
HM. Hot Milo (S$1.2) Qty:  20 
IC. Iced Coffee (S$1.5) Qty:  2 
HC. Hot Coffee (S$1.2) Qty:  0 
1P. 100 Plus (S$1.1) Qty:  50 
CC. Coca Cola (S$1.3) Qty:  50
```

Instead my output is like this:

```
None Iced Milo (S$1.5) Qty:  2 

None Hot Milo (S$1.2) Qty:  20 

None Iced Coffee (S$1.5) Qty:  2 

None Hot Coffee (S$1.2) Qty:  0 

None 100 Plus (S$1.1) Qty:  50 

None Coca Cola (S$1.3) Qty:  50
```

Here is my code:

```
nested_dictionary = {
    "IM.": {
        "description": "Iced Milo",
        "price": "(S$1.5)",
        "quantity": "%d" % (int(IMquantity)),
    },
    "HM.": {
        "description": "Hot Milo",
        "price": "(S$1.2)",
        "quantity": "%d" % (int(HMquantiy)),
    },
    "IC.": {
        "description": "Iced Coffee",
        "price": "(S$1.5)",
        "quantity": "%d" % (int(ICquantity)),
    },
    "HC.": {
        "description": "Hot Coffee",
        "price": "(S$1.2)",
        "quantity": "%d" % (int(pprint)),
    },
    "1P.": {
        "description": "100 Plus",
        "price": "(S$1.1)",
        "quantity": "%d" % (int(onePquantity)),
    },
    "CC.": {
        "description": "Coca Cola",
        "price": "(S$1.3)",
        "quantity": "%d" % (int(CCquantity)),
    },
}
for x in nested_dictionary:
    print(nested_dictionary, end=" ")
    print(nested_dictionary[x]["description"], end=" ")
    print(nested_dictionary[x]["price"], end=" ")
    if nested_dictionary[x]["quantity"] == 0:
        print("Qty: ***out of stock***\n")
    else:
        print("Qty: ", nested_dictionary[x]["quantity"], "\n")
```

Comment: Your code is missing the values for `IMquantity`, etc... Also, I think the idea of the exercise here would be to only format your data as you're printing it; saving strings of integers or prices in the dicts sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: You want `print(x, end="")` instead of `print(nested_dictionary, end=" ")`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reformulation of your code to use a list of products (if you wanted, turning that into a dict-of-dicts is a single dictionary comprehension away: `nested_dictionary = {p["code"]: p for p in products}`.

In addition, we're using [`.format_map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map), which accepts a mapping (e.g. a dictionary) and [formats a string](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/string.html#formatstrings) using the given format string and data in that dict.

```
products = [
    {
        "code": "IM",
        "description": "Iced Milo",
        "price": 1.5,
        "quantity": 2,
    },
    {
        "code": "HM",
        "description": "Hot Milo",
        "price": 1.2,
        "quantity": 20,
    },
    {
        "code": "IC",
        "description": "Iced Coffee",
        "price": 1.5,
        "quantity": 2,
    },
    {
        "code": "HC",
        "description": "Hot Coffee",
        "price": 1.2,
        "quantity": 0,
    },
    {
        "code": "1P",
        "description": "100 Plus",
        "price": 1.1,
        "quantity": 50,
    },
    {
        "code": "CC",
        "description": "Coca Cola",
        "price": 1.3,
        "quantity": 50,
    },
]

for product in products:
    line = "{code}. {description} (S${price:.2f}) Qty: {quantity}".format_map(product)
    print(line)
```

The output is

```
IM. Iced Milo (S$1.50) Qty: 2
HM. Hot Milo (S$1.20) Qty: 20
IC. Iced Coffee (S$1.50) Qty: 2
HC. Hot Coffee (S$1.20) Qty: 0
1P. 100 Plus (S$1.10) Qty: 50
CC. Coca Cola (S$1.30) Qty: 50
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in nested_dictionary:
    print(x, nested_dictionary[x]['description'], nested_dictionary[x]['price'], 'Qty:', end=' ')
    if int(nested_dictionary[x]['quantity']) == 0:
            print("***out of stock***")
    else:
        print(nested_dictionary[x]['quantity'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the dict.items() to iterate over the dictionary
Here is the code

```
for (key,value) in nested_dictionary.items():
    print(key,end=' ')
    print(value['description'],end=' ')
    print(value['price'],end=' ')
    if (value['quantity'] == 0):
        print("Qty: ***out of stock***\n")
    else:
        print(value['quantity']), "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the name of the keys, you will have to add the following in your for loop:

```
print(x, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to change your code as little as possible, here is the solution I got.

1. I changed the first print line to print the value of 'x' instead of trying to index into the dictionary again.
2. I changed the way the quantity key was stored, as instead of using the % operators, you can directly store the value as ints. This is the final code I got:

```
nested_dictionary = {'IM.': {'description': 'Iced Milo', 'price': '(S$1.5)', 'quantity': int(IMquantity)},
                             'HM.': {'description': 'Hot Milo', 'price': '(S$1.2)', 'quantity': int(HMquantiy)},
                             'IC.': {'description': 'Iced Coffee', 'price': '(S$1.5)', 'quantity': int(ICquantity)},
                             'HC.': {'description': 'Hot Coffee', 'price': '(S$1.2)', 'quantity': int(pprint)},
                             '1P.': {'description': '100 Plus', 'price': '(S$1.1)', 'quantity': int(onePquantity)},
                             'CC.': {'description': 'Coca Cola', 'price': '(S$1.3)', 'quantity': int(CCquantity)}
for x in nested_dictionary:
    print(x, end=' ')
    print(nested_dictionary[x]['description'], end=' ')
    print(nested_dictionary[x]['price'], end=' ')
    if nested_dictionary[x]['quantity'] == 0:
            print("Qty: ***out of stock***\n")
    else:
            print("Qty: ", nested_dictionary[x]['quantity'], "\n")
```